# Codemirror diff

Tags: diff, codemirror, codemirror-modes

I want to implement diff mode using codemirror (not the merge tool). something like: git diff. I used Codemirror official diff mode, however, not able to get the tokenizer (+, -) when the user has added or changed something.

Answer (score 2):

The CodeMirror Diff Mode just highlights a row based on its format (e.g. it highlights a row with a green colour if it starts with "+" or with red colour if it starts with "-"). You need to generate the diff text by yourself. There are several libraries which you can use for it, for example [jsdiff](https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff)

You can get the diff between 2 texts like this:

```
import * as Diff from 'diff';

var text1=`
line1
line2
line3
`;

var text2=`
line0

line3

line4
line5
`;

var diff = Diff.createTwoFilesPatch('old', 'new', text1, text2, { context: 1 });
console.log('diff', diff);
```

It will produce the following diff:

```
diff ===================================================================
--- old [object Object]
+++ new
@@ -1,4 +1,7 @@
 
-line1
-line2
+line0
+
 line3
+
+line4
+line5
```

And after is you can insert this text into CodeMirror.